# how to unpack specific items of dictionary into variables by using loop

Tags: python, dictionary, variables

I have some dynamic items in dictionary type. I want to unpack some of them into variables. I want to know some methods by using loop.

I have 'self.params = {}' to store basis and weights. Maybe 10 or 20 b and W, which depend on parameters into class. I want to unpack it into 'W1','W2'.....,'b1','b2'.....I have layer number in 'hidden_dims'

I want to realize some functions like follow false code:

```py
for i in range(hidden_dims):
  W(i+1) = self.params['W%s'% str(i+1)]
  b(i+1) = self.params['b%s'% str(i+1)]
```

Then I can get some variables like:'W1','W2'...'Wn'(and n = hidden_dims) and 'b1','b2'...'bn'

can it be realized?

Comment: What is circles

Comment: Sorry, it is loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create variables dynamically using global(). Something like this:

```
for i in range(1, hidden_dims + 1):
    w = 'W' + str(i)
    b = 'b' + str(i)

    global()[w] = self.params[w]
    global()[b] = self.params[b]
```

Note: It is not advisable to try and create variables dynamically. For your use case, the use of two lists W[] and b[] seems like a much cleaner way to store the values